# Back propagation Randomized initial weights

Tags: java, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I am working on a neural network that learns through back propagation. I've done some research and apparently randomized initial weights are essential.

However, the error or cost of the final configuration of weights is almost the exact same initializing to random numbers and to 1/n (n being the number of neurons in that layer). And it turns out the final set of weights when it is initialized to 1/n isn't fully "random". Which makes me think that there is an important step that I'm missing that makes the algorithm see no difference between a neural network with a lot of hidden layers and neurons and a neural network with one hidden layer with one neuron. That would explain why the error is the same with the symmetry unbroken (through randomization) or with only one hidden layer and one neuron.
These are the results:
[1/n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDLsf.png)[Random](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9B6x.png)

If anyone has any clue about what the problem could be, please let me know.